# UITableView does not display all content right away (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a standard `UITableView` with dynamic cells, that is located in a normal `ViewController`.
The cells have a Right Detail storyboard style and everything runs smoothly, except for one strange behavior.
In the table functions I fill both, the `cell.textlabel?.text`  and the `cell.detailTextLabel?.text` with some text, but when I segue to that view I only see the `textLabel` in the beginning. In order for the details text to show up, I need to interact with the table, i.e. scroll it up or down and only then the detail section of the table starts showing the text.
Does anybody know why is this happening?

**EDIT**

My code for filling the table

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // load the history
    // deque the reusable cell
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("historyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // grab the history as an array of strings
    if var history = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("history") as? [String]
    {
        var historySingleton = split(history[indexPath.row]) {$0 == "+"}

        // format the date
        var dateUnits = split(historySingleton[1]) {$0 == " "}
        var theDate = dateUnits[0]
        var theTime = dateUnits[1]

        var theTimeParticles = split(theTime) {$0 == ":"}
        var theDateParticles = split(theDate) {$0 == "-"}

        var finalDateString =
        "\(theTimeParticles[0])" + ":" + "\(theTimeParticles[1])" + ", "
        + "\(theDateParticles[2])" + "." + "\(theDateParticles[1])" + "." + "\(theDateParticles[0])"

        // the content of the history cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = historySingleton[0] // the length of the timer
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = finalDateString // the date and time of the history record
    }

    // make the cells unselectable
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    return cell
}
```

Comment: as soon as you do the first drag of finger, all the cells showing update automatically? or just the new cells?

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: @iosDev82
I am not sure I quite understand the question. There are no new cells to be displayed and all the right parts of the cells start appearing when I scroll through the table

Comment: @Aladin what code in particular would you like to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, that I am doing some formatting and computations in the function that fills the table with data, so I figured it had something to do with that.

I tried calling `reloadData()` on `viewDidLoad()` in `dispatch_async` on main thread and that actually loads everything right away